# Proving that a language with a regular expression is context-free

Tags: context-free-grammar, regular-expressions

If L = {ww : w ∈ L(1*01*)} it means that w = $1^a$0$1^b$ and ww = $1^a$0$1^b$$1^a$0$1^b$

If I want to prove that this language is context-free by giving a context-free grammar, can I give a CF grammar for $1^a$0$1^a$$1^b$0$1^b$? Would it be the same thing? I'm switching the order of the inner 1's, since if a = 2 and b = 3, there will be 5 inner 1's and it doesn't seem to matter if its the 2 a's or the 3 a's that come first.

Comment: That's right, it doesn't matter, as long as the strings accepted by the regular expression and those accepted by the CFG are identical.  It looks like you know how to do that, is that right?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you replace $1^b1^a$ with $1^a1^b$ or $1^{a+b}$, and not a new free parameter like $1^c$, then yes it is the same language. So all you need to do is to be able to generate $1^a01^a$ for any $a$, and then by starting with the rule $S \to AB$ where $A$ and $B$ have the same grammar representation that gives $1^a01^a$ or $1^b01^b$ for arbitrary $a,b$ then you are done.